# In React-Native, the internal child elements of the Android parent element are definitely positioned beyond the parent element to be hidden

Tags: react-native

[this is my genymotion screen !!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJDur.png)

**this is my code . Just react-native program And the trouble in my photo.Android is Not , IOS is great .how hack in android to make it right .**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TestScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text></Text>
                <View style={styles.parent}>
                    <View style={styles.children}>
                        <Text>my content </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    parent: {
        width:300,
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        alignItems:'center',
        position:'absolute',
    },
    children:{
        height:20,
        justifyContent: 'center',

        top:-10
    }
})
```

***How should I Fix it***

Comment: Please share your code here

Comment: I shared . please help

Comment: why you use `top:-10` ? can you remove it and try

Comment: Because I want to suspend the text on the parent container, but the excess part is hidden.

Comment: can you try `top:0` and see what happens

Comment: Is Normal , but I want the text to float beyond the text

Comment: is this is what you looking? https://codesandbox.io/s/8297nq9k32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow is not supported on Android: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802

You can try this library:
https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow

Or you could try to do some sort of absolute positioning with your view, but it might not be perfect. The below example puts all of the views in one parent, and then offsets the text to overlap both with an absolute position.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ height: 40}}/>
            <View style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}/>
            <View style={{ position: "absolute", top: 30}}>
                <Text>my content </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```